# Il caso "bulgaro"

Tags: word-usage, etymology

Il termine "bulgaro" viene usato con riferimento ad atteggiamenti intolleranti o a discipline tipiche dei regimi totalitari.

Forse il caso più noto è quello dell'[editto bulgaro](https://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Editto_bulgaro) di Berlusconi. In altri casi si fa riferimento a *percentuali bulgare*, quando la partecipazione a delle  elezioni sono altissime senza che ci siano molte opzioni nella scelta.

Domanda: perché si fa riferimento all'aggettivo "bulgaro" in questi casi e non ad esempio a "russo", "cinese" o "cubano" etc. per far riferimento ad un regime totalitario?

Comment: Io sempre avevo pensato che si dicesse "editto bulgaro" perché si basava in una dichiarazione di Berlusconi fatta a Sofia.

Answer (score 7):

L'espressione presa a riferimento è la **maggioranza bulgara** che indica maggioranza schiaccante di consensi senza un dibattito libero.

L'espressione prende spunto dalla situazione politica della Bulgaria (nell'epoca socialista), quando era il più fedele alleato dell'U.R.S.S., ma anche quello in cui il dibattito politico interno era inesistente.

Il caso Berlusconi e l'editto bulgaro rientrano in questa accezione, coincidenza volle, all'epoca che il Primo Ministro fosse in visita a Sofia.

Sul sito della Treccani, c'è un [**approfondimento**](http://www.treccani.it/lingua_italiana/articoli/scritto_e_parlato/parole_bulgare.html) a tal proposito, nel paragrafo *Cose da socialismo reale*

Comment: Grazie per il link all'articolo sul sito della Treccani, che chiarisce che questo uso dell'aggettivo “bulgaro” è precedente all'episodio berlusconiano (2002) e risale a metà degli anni Novanta.

Comment: Tutto molto chiaro, mi chiedo perché la "Bulgaria" sia diventata l'emblema dei regimi totalitari tanto da entrare nel linguaggio comune, quando molti altri stati nello stesso periodo lo erano.

Comment: Il regime dell'allora Bulgaria socialista era noto per dichiarazione particolarmente accondiscendenti verso il preteso ruolo guida dell'URSS,  e suscitavano ironie anche negli ambienti più disposti a favore dell'URSS. Suppongo sia un modo di dire in uso solo in Italia, e probabilmente solo in certe ambienti.

Comment: Anch'io l'ho trovato molto interessante.

Comment: Secondo me c'entra anche la fonetica: _BULG!_ È quasi onomatopeico...

Answer (score 4):

L'espressione **maggioranza bulgara** fa riferimento all'**esito sostanzialmente unanime di una votazione**, ad una schiacciante maggioranza di consensi,  sottointendendo anche la **mancanza di un libero dibattito**.

Nel Referendum del 1946 in cui si votò tra monanrchia e repubblica, **si ebbe una maggioranza a favore della repubblica del 95.6%, con un'adesione (ossia affluenza alle urne) del 91.7%**, a seguito del quale fu proclamata la Repubblica Popolare di Bulgaria a guida del *Partito Comunista  (БКП)* (guidato da Dimitrov da cui prese il nome la Costituzione del 1947). Seguirono poi nella storia della Bulgaria il Patto di Varsavia, il COMECON e il vincolo all'URSS durante la Guerra Fredda.

In particolare la Bulgaria registrò una maggiornza elevatissima nel referendum costituzionale del 16 Maggio 1971. I cittadini votarono la cosiddetta Costituzione Zhivkov, il cui primo articolo sanciva il ruolo guida del Partito Comunista. **Il risultato fu del 99.7% dei voti a favore, con un'adesione del 99.7% (ossia 100% dei votanti)**.

Da questi eventi storici prende l'avvio nel linguaggio, soprattutto giornalistico, di maggioranza bulgara con il riferimento negativo legato alla mancanza di libero dibattito.

Con **editto bulgaro** si fa invece riferimento ad una dichiarazione di [Silvio Berlusconi](http://www.treccani.it/magazine/lingua_italiana/articoli/scritto_e_parlato/parole_bulgare.html) rilasciata nell'aprile del 2002 in occasione di una visita ufficiale a Sofia contro l'uso a suo dire criminoso della tv pubblica da parte di Enzo Biagi, Michele Santoro e Daniele Luttazzi, e l'indicazione di un preciso dovere della nuova dirigenza Rai dell'impedire il ripetersi di tali eventi.

La **connotazione negativa** che invece accompagna l'aggettivo **bulgaro** ha invece radici profonde.

In Francia il termine "*bulgaro*" assume le sue connotazioni peggiori e più infamanti. Nel linguaggio comune dei Francesi abbiamo addirittura delle imprecazioni che fanno chiaro riferimento alla "bulgarità": *Bougre d'idiot!* ("pezzo d'idiota!"), l'avverbio *bougrement* ("maledettamente").

Tale connotazione negativa, presumibilmente, è da mettere in stretta relazione con l'espansione dell'eresia "bulgara" per eccellenza, il **bogomilismo**.

Dal XIII secolo si assiste infatti alla proliferazione del termine "bulgaro" come variante di "eretico" in alcuni cronisti occidentali. Il primo a fare questo uso del termine "bulgaro" è il cronista Roberto d'Auxerre in relazione a talune posizioni eretiche di un tale Cavalier d'Evrand: "heieresis illius, quam Bulgarorum vocant", nel 1201.

Da allora la "fortuna" del termine "bulgaro" (Bulgri, Bugari, Burgar, Bugares, Bugri, Bogri, Boulgres e altre varianti latino medioevali) come sinonimo di "deviante", di "uomo cattivo e perverso" sul piano umano, oltre che spirituale anche sessuale.

Il monaco Alberico del monastero delle Tre Fonti, nel 1239 d. C., scriveva nella sua cronaca: "Il 31 maggio, al monte Wimer [in Francia] furono bruciati molti Bulgari per compiacere Dio. Su un grande rogo si fecero ardere 183 Bulgari, al cospetto del re di Navarra, di numerosi baroni della Champagne e di molti vescovi...".

In italiano il verbo **[buggerare](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/buggerare/)** deriva del lat. mediev. Bulgarus «Bulgaro», e per estens. «eretico», «usuraio», da cui, come epiteto offensivo, «sodomita». Il significato originario era *Sodomizzare, avere rapporti sodomitici*, sebbene oggi si usi per lo più nel significato di *truffare, ingannare*.

Secondo il Panzini, deriva invece da *bugio*=*buco*. Sebbene appaia normalmente nei vocabolari moderni e sia tuttora utilizzata nella lingua parlata, la parola sembra essere rimasta “sospesa” nell'Ottocento, secolo nel quale la gran parte dei vocabolari (Tommaseo, Cardinali Borrelli, Rigutini-Fanfani, D'Alberti di Villanuova, Panlessico) non la prende nemmeno in considerazione.

*Buggera* è sciocchezza, fandonia, ma anche stizza, rabbia, ira. Anche il Pianigiani, che cita la Crusca, registra la derivazione da [bugio= buco](http://www.etimo.it/?term=buggerare); e avverte: “voce plebea”. Ad ogni modo, il significato antico è “sodomizzare, avere rapporti sodomitici”. Si veda anche [qui](http://www.etimo.it/?cmd=id&id=2704&md=804c0d432eb08b7b570d47589b5cb5f0).

La *liaison tra imbrogliare e sodomizzare è consolidata*.

Molti fanno derivare la parola **buggera** dal latino medievale *Bugerus*, variante di *bulgarus*.  I bulgari, in quanto seguaci dell'eresia patarina, subirono, come tutti gli eretici, ogni sorta di accuse infamanti; tra le più gravi, a quei tempi, era la sodomia. Secondo il Devoto-Oli il traslato deriva “dall'identica pena che era riservata agli eretici e ai sodomiti” ; quindi buggero=sodomita.

Il pregiudizio anti-bulgaro in Occidente ha quindi radici molto antiche.

Comment: Complimenti per queste e le tue altre risposte circostanziatissime! Due piccoli commenti: 1) Che cosa intendi di preciso qui per “adesione”? La cosiddetta “affluenza alle urne” (cioè la percentuale di aventi diritto al voto che ha effettivamente votato)? 2) A proposito della fama negativa dei bulgari, potresti accennare anche al verbo “buggerare”, soprattutto nel suo significato originario.

Comment: @DaG Grazie! 1) sì, affluenza alle urne 2) ho integrato.